# How to use a due date and task progress to create an overall status?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with due dates in column B and task progress (% complete) in column C.

```
Column A    Column B       Column C           Column D
Task ID     Due Date       Task Complete      Status

001         10/1/2018      90%
002         10/1/2018      25%
003         10/22/2018     75%
004         10/22/2018     50%
005         10/31/2018     0%
```

based off of that data I would like to use column D to insert the overall status based on some defined scoring:

- 90% and within one week of due date = On Track
- 75% - 89% and within one week of due date = At Risk
- 74% - 50% and within one week of due date = Off Schedule
- 49% - 0% and within one week of due date = In trouble

Is it possible to use a formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, what you ask for may be achieved with a formula such as:

```
=IF(B4-TODAY()<8,CHOOSE(MATCH(C4,{0,0.5,0.75,0.9}),"In trouble","Off Schedule", "At Risk","On Track"),"")
```

but this may only give meaningful results for jobs that take around one month each. You should possibly be taking start dates into account. For example a job that only requires a week to complete is not very likely to be in trouble if say 40% complete after say one day.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. This can be achieved using a look up table.

We'll define a lookup table based on the criteria you defined and name the table StatusTable. If you are unfamiliar with data tables in excel read this link: [Data Tables](https://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html)

We can then match the task complete percentage to the percent column in the table using the two formulas INDEX & MATCH. It is important to note that due to the way you want values returned we actually need to make the values in the percent column slightly less than your criteria. For example, if we want to return a status of 90% or higher as "On Track" then we need to define At Risk at a value below 90%. Otherwise, we will return the wrong value.

Here is the final output. The INDEX MATCH formula is in column D. Column F is showing the formula that is in column D. Column H&I is where the StatusTable is created. [Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENq7P.png)